# Type alias with "using" inside class cannot be used as return type

Tags: c++, using, using-directives

I'm currently switching from Java to C++ and I have troubling understaning the following problem.

I have a header file for a class (`AClass.h`):

```
#ifndef ACLASS_H
#define ACLASS_H

#include <cstdint>

class AClass {
public:
    using byte = uint8_t;
private:
    byte data;
public:
    byte* getData();
    void setData(const byte* newData);
}

#endif
```

I try the following implementation (`AClass.cxx`):

```
#include "AClass.h"

// This works fine.
void AClass::setData(const byte* theData) {
    // ...
}

// 'byte' does not name a type.
byte* AClass::getData() {
    return &data;
}
```

Using the "type" `byte` as a parameter type works just fine. But using it as a return value, does not. Using `AClass::byte* AClass::getData()` does work, but I cannot graps why that is?

Why do I have to use the name of the class to use the type?

Comment: Your function should return `AClass::byte*` because the function is defined in the global scope and there is no type in the global scope named `byte`.  You have defined it inside `AClass`.

Comment: Because your `using` statement is at the class-level, under `AClass`. If you want to reference a definition made at the class level, then you'll need the class to do so. That said, it may be better to make it non-public and/or only use that type within the implementation file.

Comment: I think the confusion of the asker might be due to the fact that inside a class' member function you can access members without prepending anything, in general. E.g. given `class A { int x; void f(); }`, `f` can make use of `x` just by writing `x`, for there's an implicity `this->` telling that the `x` is the member of the class. For aliases there's no equivalent shortcut, no implicit `ThisVeryClass::` prepended to the member types, and you always have to fully qualify the name.

Comment: You have the option of specifying the return type last instead of first ("trailing return type"), like `auto AClass::getData() -> byte`, and then it works, because the compiler has now seen that the function is an `AClass` member.